# JQuery - Select All CheckBoxes within current table only

Tags: jquery

I have two nested repeaters in C#.  The outer has some grouping information and the inner has a table with X number of checkboxes.

So I will have Y number of tables.  At the top of each table there will be a check box (as well as a checkbox on each row).  What I want to do is be able to select all check boxes in a single table from the checkbox at the top of each table.

I can select ALL checkboxes in one go as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#checkboxflipflop").click(function() {
            var checked_status = this.checked;
            $(".storecheckbox input").each(function() {
                this.checked = checked_status;
            });
        });
    });
```

I just can't figure out how to narrow the selection to the current table, (the checkbox at the top of each table is in the th row).

Thanks

EDIT.... sorry forgot to mention that we are on 1.26 of JQuery and not sure if I am allowed to move us up at all.  Which means "closest" is not there.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Something like the following ought to do it

```
$('th input:checkbox').click(function(e) {

var table = $(e.target).closest('table');
$('td input:checkbox', table).attr('checked', e.target.checked);

});
```

Here's a **[Working Demo](http://jsbin.com/evome)** with two tables nested in another table *(semantically horrible I'll admit)*. Add **/edit** to the URL to see the code

**EDIT:**

Since you're still using jQuery 1.2.6, use `parents()` instead of `closest()`

```
$('th input:checkbox').click(function(e) {

var table = $(e.target).parents('table:first');
$('td input:checkbox', table).attr('checked', e.target.checked);

});
```

Comment: Wouldn't this mean that checking any checkbox (not just the master one) would check all the others in that table?

Comment: no, as the click event handler binding selector is applied to checkboxes that are *descendents* of `<th>` elements. I've interpreted it that all other checkboxes are contained within `<td>` elements in each table

Comment: if the OP's HTML is correct, the `<th>` elements should be inside `<tr>` elements i.e. `<th>` elements are like `<td>` elements, but for header content

Answer (score 6):

So each table has a "check all" checkbox, right? Why not give it a class of `.checkall`? Then you could do this (untested):

```
$('.checkall').click(function(){
  var checked_status = this.checked;
  $(this).closest('table').find('input:checkbox').each(function(){
    this.checked = checked_status;
  });
})
```

Alternately, if you don't want to use the `.checkall` class, you use a selector like:

```
$('.storecheckbox input:nth-child(1)').click`
```

Meaning, "when the first input inside an element with class `.storecheckbox` is clicked..."

Answer (score 2):

Here's the snippet that should work as per your current design of the page.

```
// iterate over all the tables in the page
$("table").each(function() {
    // attach a click event on the checkbox in the header in each of table
    $(this).find("th:first input:checkbox").click(function() {
        var val = this.checked;
        // when clicked on a particular header, get the reference of the table & hence all the rows in that table, iterate over each of them.
        $(this).parents("table").find("tr").each(function() {
            // access the checkbox in the first column, and updates its value.
            $(this).find("td:first input:checkbox")[0].checked = val;
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).closest("table").find("input:checkbox")
```

Note: It seems that all the select-all-in-this-table-checkboxes have the same `id`, the `id` should be unique within the page, you should use a class instead. (Or just `table th input`)

Answer (score 0):

// This works for me

```
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th><asp:CheckBox ID="chkHeader" runat="server" Visible="false" /></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkRow" runat="server" Visible="false" onclick="handleClick(this);"/>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkForDisplayGrayed" runat="server" Visible="false"/>
        </td>

    </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var result = $('#tableEmployeeRecords').dataTable({
        "oLanguage": {
            "sSearch": "Filter: ",
            "sEmptyTable": "No results found."
        },
        "columnDefs": [{
            // Set column 0 to non sortable, checkbox hearder is placed
            "targets": [0],
            "orderable": false
        }],
        "order": [[1, "asc"]]
    });
    // Check Uncheck Select All 
        $('table [id*=chkHeader]').click(function () {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                $('table [id*=chkRow]').prop('checked', true);
            }
            else {
                $('table [id*=chkRow]').prop('checked', false);
            }
        });
    });
    // Check Uncheck Row items and Select All 
        function handleClick(cb)
        {
            var totalRow = $('table [id*=chkRow]').length; 
            var checkSelected = $('table [id*=chkRow]:checked').length;

            if (checkSelected == totalRow )
                $("#tableEmployeeRecords [id*=chkHeader]").prop("checked", true);
            else
                $("#tableEmployeeRecords [id*=chkHeader]").removeAttr("checked");
        }
</script>
```