# How to fix code have select all asp:CheckBoxList within current table only in .NET C# same as "JQuery - Select All CheckBoxes within..." question?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, checkboxlist

How to fix code have select all **asp:CheckBoxList** within current table only in .NET C# same as "JQuery - Select All CheckBoxes within current table only" question ?

Because I try coding with sample but can't select all **asp:CheckBoxList** within current table only.

Link to ["JQuery - Select All CheckBoxes within current table only"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1742010/jquery-select-all-checkboxes-within-current-table-only/1742792)  question.

My snipplet to describe problem.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script
    type="text/javascript"
    src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>

<style>
form , p , td, th{
  font-size: 24px;
}
input.largerCheckbox
{
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Show checkboxes:</h1>

<p><label><input type="checkbox" class="largerCheckbox" id="checkAll"/> Check all</label></p>

<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name"><br><br>

<table id="myTable">
  <tr class="header">
    <th>Checkbox</th>
    <th>Number</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="largerCheckbox" name="vehicle1" value="1"></td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="largerCheckbox" name="vehicle2" value="11"></td>
    <td>11</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="largerCheckbox" name="vehicle3" value="111"></td>
    <td>111</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="largerCheckbox" name="vehicle4" value="1111"></td>
    <td>1111</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="largerCheckbox" name="vehicle5" value="11111"></td>
    <td>11111</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }       
  }
}
</script>

<script>
$("#checkAll").change(function () {
    $("input:checkbox").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

My full source code.

https://github.com/doanga2007/CheckLoopQR3

Sample code at the bottom.

1. Default.aspx (HTML Code)

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="CheckLoopQR3.Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<style>
    #myInput {
        font-size: 16px;
        padding: 6px 20px 6px 10px;
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
        margin-bottom: 3px;
    }
</style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function(){
    $("#checkAll").change(function () {
    $("input:checkbox").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
    });
    });
    </script>
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
            input = document.getElementById("myInput");
            filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
            table = document.getElementById("CheckBox1");
            tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
            for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
                td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
                if (td) {
                    txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
                    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                        tr[i].style.display = "";
                    } else {
                        tr[i].style.display = "none";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div class="container">
            <h2>QR Code Generator</h2>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Please Input Data</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtQRCode" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                <asp:Button ID="btnGenerate" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-secondary" Text="Generate" OnClick="btnGenerate_Click" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <asp:Button ID="btnSelect" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-secondary" Text="Display Text" OnClick="btnSelect_Click" /><br /><br />

            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>

            <asp:CheckBox ID="checkAll" runat="server" Font-Size="Large"/><asp:Label id="checkTextAll" runat="server" Font-Size="Large"></asp:Label><br /><br />

            <label>Input Number to Search &nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
            <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()"><br /><br />

            <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Border="1"
            BorderColor="LightGray" Font-Size="Large"></asp:CheckBoxList>  

        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

2. Default.aspx.cs (C# Code)

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using ZXing;
using ZXing.QrCode;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

namespace CheckLoopQR3
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.checkTextAll.Text = " Check All";
        }
        protected void btnSelect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string code = txtQRCode.Text;
            long num = Convert.ToInt64(code);

            int i;

            for (i = 1; i < 6; i++)
            {
                num *= i;
                CheckBox1.Items.Add(new ListItem(" " + num));
            }
        }
        protected void btnGenerate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (CheckBox1.SelectedItem == null)
            {
                Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
            }

            string[] texture = { "Selected Text 1 -> ", "Selected Text 2 -> ", "Selected Text 3 -> ",
                                 "Selected Text 4 -> ", "Selected Text 5 -> "};

            string[] texture2 = { " is Checkbox 1.", " is Checkbox 2.", " is Checkbox 3.",
                                 " is Checkbox 4.", " is Checkbox 5."};

            foreach (ListItem listItem in CheckBox1.Items)
            {
                if (listItem.Selected)
                {
                    int a = CheckBox1.Items.IndexOf(listItem);
                    a = a + 1;

                    string code = listItem.Text;

                    CheckBox1.Visible = false;
                    checkAll.Visible = false;
                    checkTextAll.Visible = false;

                    QrCodeEncodingOptions options = new QrCodeEncodingOptions();

                    options = new QrCodeEncodingOptions
                    {
                        DisableECI = true,
                        CharacterSet = "UTF-8",
                        Width = 150,
                        Height = 150,
                        Margin = 0,
                    };

                    var barcodeWriter = new BarcodeWriter();
                    barcodeWriter.Format = BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE;
                    barcodeWriter.Options = options;

                    System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image imgBarCode = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();
                    imgBarCode.Height = 150;
                    imgBarCode.Width = 150;

                    Label lblvalues = new Label();
                    lblvalues.Text += texture[a - 1] + listItem.Text + texture2[a - 1];
                    lblvalues.Font.Size = FontUnit.Large;

                    using (Bitmap bitMap = barcodeWriter.Write(code))
                    {
                        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                        {
                            bitMap.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                            byte[] byteImage = ms.ToArray();
                            imgBarCode.ImageUrl = "data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(byteImage);
                        }
                        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(imgBarCode);
                        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new HtmlGenericControl("br"));
                        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(lblvalues);
                        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new HtmlGenericControl("br"));
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //do something else 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The code snippet doesn't match the aspx. When you mentioned the current table, you mean `myTable` or a `DataTable`? Basically, you want to let the aspx to achieve the same thing code snippet does?

Comment: @Sumate your question is not clear. Please rephrase it properly.

Comment: @蕭為元 I let snippet code simulate result to asp:CheckBoxList within current table only in .NET C# , because I do not have ASP.NET hosting to snippet html code to simulate result and [vdo to describe problem](https://doanga2007.github.io/bug2.mp4).

Comment: @Rohan Rao I rephrase question to reference to same as ["JQuery - Select All CheckBoxes within current table only"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1742010/jquery-select-all-checkboxes-within-current-table-only/1742792) question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Good news :** I have answer to fix code have select all asp:CheckBoxList within current table only in .NET C# same as "JQuery - Select All CheckBoxes within current table only" question.

Key of answer to "jQuery :visible Selector".

jQuery :

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $("#checkAll").change(function () {
        $("input:checkbox:visible").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
    });
});
```

My snipplet to another solve problem in HTML.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script
    type="text/javascript"
    src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>

<style>
form , p , td, th{
  font-size: 24px;
}
input.largerCheckbox
{
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Show checkboxes:</h1>

<p><label><input type="checkbox" class="largerCheckbox" id="checkAll"/> Check all</label></p>

<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name"><br><br>

<table id="myTable">
  <tr class="header">
    <th>Checkbox</th>
    <th>Number</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="largerCheckbox" name="vehicle1" value="1"></td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="largerCheckbox" name="vehicle2" value="11"></td>
    <td>11</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="largerCheckbox" name="vehicle3" value="111"></td>
    <td>111</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="largerCheckbox" name="vehicle4" value="1111"></td>
    <td>1111</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="largerCheckbox" name="vehicle5" value="11111"></td>
    <td>11111</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }       
  }
}
</script>

<script>
$("#checkAll").change(function () {
    $("input:checkbox:visible").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

My full source code.

https://github.com/doanga2007/CheckLoopQR3

1. Default.aspx (HTML Code)

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="CheckLoopQR3.Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<style>
    #myInput {
        font-size: 16px;
        padding: 6px 20px 6px 10px;
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
        margin-bottom: 3px;
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function(){
    $("#checkAll").change(function () {
    $("input:checkbox:visible").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
    });
    });
</script>

<script>
        function myFunction() {
            var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
            input = document.getElementById("myInput");
            filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
            table = document.getElementById("CheckBox1");
            tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
            for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
                td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
                if (td) {
                    txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
                    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                        tr[i].style.display = "";
                    } else {
                        tr[i].style.display = "none";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div class="container">
            <h2>QR Code Generator</h2>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Please Input Data</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtQRCode" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                <asp:Button ID="btnGenerate" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-secondary" Text="Generate" OnClick="btnGenerate_Click" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <label>Input Number to Search &nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
            <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()"><br />

            <asp:Button ID="btnSelect" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-secondary" Text="Display Text" OnClick="btnSelect_Click" /><br /><br />

            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>

            <asp:CheckBox ID="checkAll" runat="server" Font-Size="Large"/><asp:Label id="checkTextAll" runat="server" Font-Size="Large"></asp:Label><br /><br />

            <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Border="1"
            BorderColor="LightGray" Font-Size="Large"></asp:CheckBoxList>  

        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

2. Default.aspx.cs (C# Code)

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using ZXing;
using ZXing.QrCode;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

namespace CheckLoopQR3
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.checkTextAll.Text = " Check All";
        }
        protected void btnSelect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string code = txtQRCode.Text;
            long num = Convert.ToInt64(code);

            int i;

            for (i = 1; i < 6; i++)
            {
                num *= i;
                CheckBox1.Items.Add(new ListItem(" " + num));
            }
        }
        protected void btnGenerate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (CheckBox1.SelectedItem == null)
            {
                Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
            }

            string[] texture = { "Selected Text 1 -> ", "Selected Text 2 -> ", "Selected Text 3 -> ",
                                 "Selected Text 4 -> ", "Selected Text 5 -> "};

            string[] texture2 = { " is Checkbox 1.", " is Checkbox 2.", " is Checkbox 3.",
                                 " is Checkbox 4.", " is Checkbox 5."};

            foreach (ListItem listItem in CheckBox1.Items)
            {
                if (listItem.Selected)
                {
                    int a = CheckBox1.Items.IndexOf(listItem);
                    a = a + 1;

                    string code = listItem.Text;

                    CheckBox1.Visible = false;
                    checkAll.Visible = false;
                    checkTextAll.Visible = false;

                    QrCodeEncodingOptions options = new QrCodeEncodingOptions();

                    options = new QrCodeEncodingOptions
                    {
                        DisableECI = true,
                        CharacterSet = "UTF-8",
                        Width = 150,
                        Height = 150,
                        Margin = 0,
                    };

                    var barcodeWriter = new BarcodeWriter();
                    barcodeWriter.Format = BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE;
                    barcodeWriter.Options = options;

                    System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image imgBarCode = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();
                    imgBarCode.Height = 150;
                    imgBarCode.Width = 150;

                    Label lblvalues = new Label();
                    lblvalues.Text += texture[a - 1] + listItem.Text + texture2[a - 1];
                    lblvalues.Font.Size = FontUnit.Large;

                    using (Bitmap bitMap = barcodeWriter.Write(code))
                    {
                        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                        {
                            bitMap.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                            byte[] byteImage = ms.ToArray();
                            imgBarCode.ImageUrl = "data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(byteImage);
                        }
                        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(imgBarCode);
                        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new HtmlGenericControl("br"));
                        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(lblvalues);
                        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new HtmlGenericControl("br"));
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //do something else 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```